# XPath how to select nodes which have children with same value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd

I'm working on a XML validator with XPath and I need to find every node (Product) with children nodes Cat1 equal Cat2. Like this:

```
<Catalog>
    <Product>
        <Cat1>ABC</Cat1>
        <Cat2>ABC</Cat2>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Cat1>123</Cat1>
        <Cat2>456</Cat2>
    </Product>
</Catalog>
```

How can I select only nodes Product having same value inside Cat1 and Cat2?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh) (an XML shell based on libxml2 I happen to maintain).

```
/Catalog/Product[Cat1 = Cat2]
```

Comment: "Thank you" on Stack Overflow = upvote / accept.